# Android Support library, Shadow on view pager below navigation bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, material-design, androiddesignsupport

We are using the new material design concept and action bar from design support library. There is weird problem of shadow over the view pager, Please have a look at the images here
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.raxis.signalapp

It has been seen only in devices with android 5.0+,

Any idea why this may be happening or solutions to avoid this?

Thanks

Comment: i think you are using custom view for shadow. That is creating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [Elevation](https://www.google.com/design/spec/what-is-material/elevation-shadows.html#elevation-shadows-elevation-android-) property which is only used on Lollipop+.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like we have to add the property elevation in the theme.

Answer (score 0):

Remove elevation.

In the layout, if you need a shadow do it like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary_dark"
        android:theme="@style/toolbarstyle"/>
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar_shadow" />
```

And the shadow layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `elevation` property of your `ActionBar` to 0.

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: @signalapp I'm glad I was able to help. Do not forget to accept answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I got it working. Setting elevation property in style or setElevation on actionbar in activity solved it for me. However the elevation does look good to some user and few said it is annoying.

Its upto to the design guy I guess.